# Guitar Cables and Semi-electric guitars

Tags: guitar

I am a total beginner at guitar and I bought myself a MPM Instruments guitar second hand for 60€. I thought it was a pretty good buy since it had a cable and a stand with it and it was a semi-electric guitar. However... I tried playing Rocksmith with the no cable fix and my first cable didn't return any sound. My second try I used a quarter inch to 3.5 mm adapter and a 3.5 mm cable (I dont know if this works the same as the other way around but I thought so :p) this time Rocksmith recognized my playing but only picked up buzzing. (+999 or -999 at tuning...) By now I am really desperate since I dont want to give 30$ to the real tone cable because my guitar might be broken and I dont think I have a way of fixing / checking this... anyone have a good idea on how to fix this? Thx a lot in advance :D!

Comment: By semi-electric do you mean electro-acoustic (acoustic guitar with e.g. a piezo pickup) or semi-hollow (electric guitar with magnetic pickups and a hollow body)?

Comment: Your question doesn't really explain what you are doing - a picture would really help.

Comment: Hey guys I am talking about an electro-acoustic guitar (I guess :/) The pickup came built in with the guitar but I dont have a visible electronics panel :/ @DrMayhem I will take a picture once I am back home again :D

Comment: Guys thanks too all of you for all the answers :D Dr Mayhem I took your advice to the heart and I went to my game shop too buy a real tone cable. This works fine with my guitar and I m rocking in Rocksmith :) I guess theres nothing wrong with it after all :p I just cant cable things right yet :D I do however get constant "volume too low" complains by rocksmith.. A way too fix it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple test to see if the electrics in your guitar work is to plug it into a guitar amp. Take it around to a friend's or even to a guitar shop - they should happily let you test it.

If it works through an amp, then the guitar is fine - then you need to look at why it may not work with Rocksmith. From what I know of the cabling, I'd suspect the no cable fix first.